# link ncurses ROS kinetic

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone !

I know there are already posts about this subject but after many tries I don't know how to resolve this problem.

This is my code "test_ncurses.cpp":

```
// test_ncurses.cpp
#include <ncurses.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{   
   initscr();    
   printw("Hello world");  
   refresh();    
   getch();    
   endwin();   
   return 0; 
}
```

In the manifest I added these lines :

```
<build_depend>ncurses++</build_depend>
<run_depend>ncurses++</run_depend>
```

And in my CMakeLists.txt :

```
find_package( PkgConfig REQUIRED )
pkg_check_modules ( ncurses++ REQUIRED ncurses++ )
add_executable(test_ncurses src/test_ncurses.cpp )
target_link_libraries(test_ncurses ${catkin_LIBRARIES}  ${ncurses++_LIBRARIES})
```

And when I want to catkin_make my project I get errors :

```
undefined reference to "initscr"
undefined reference to "printw"
undefined reference to "refresh"
undefined reference to "stdscr"
undefined reference to "wgetch"
undefined reference to "endwin"
```

Do you have any ideas ?

Thank you in advance !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255149/link-ncurses-ros-kinetic/) by [matt27110](https://answers.ros.org/users/29236/matt27110/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2017-02-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-21**:
I'm not sure, but I can imagine that a `+` is not a valid character in a CMake identifier. See [cmake-language - Syntax](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-language.7.html#syntax).

Can you try using `pkg_check_modules ( ncurses++ REQUIRED ncursespp)` and see if that changes anything?

**Comment by [matt27110](https://answers.ros.org/users/29236/matt27110/) on 2017-02-21**:
Not working :/

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:367 (message):
  A required package was not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Eureka !!

I removed the 2 lines in the manifest and the pkg_check_modules in the CMakeLIsts.
Then I replaced ncurses++ by Curses and it works !

```
find_package(Curses REQUIRED)
add_executable(test_ncurses src/test_ncurses.cpp )
target_link_libraries(test_ncurses ${catkin_LIBRARIES}  ${Curses_LIBRARIES})
```

---

Originally posted by [matt27110](https://answers.ros.org/users/29236/matt27110/) with karma: 98 on 2017-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-21**:
`Curses` is indeed the name of the find script that CMake uses with ncurses. See also [cmake-modules(7) - Curses](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindCurses.html).

**Comment by [Avio](https://answers.ros.org/users/19863/avio/) on 2018-07-06**:
On Ubuntu 16.04 with Kinetic, it's `${CURSES_LIBRARIES}` (all uppercase). You can see it in the heading of `/usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindCurses.cmake`.